# Grabbing text inbetween specific HTML tags using Java switch statement

Tags: java, string, text, switch-statement, tokenize

I'm trying to grab the text between `<AU></AU>` tags in a file, and then print out the results on a new line. I need to do this with a switch statements and a helper class called CharacterFromFileReader, which reads each character in a file one by one.

This is the code that I have come up with so far:

```
package code;

import java.util.HashMap;

import util.general.CharacterFromFileReader;

public class HW4 {

String _toReturn = "";

public void authorScanner(String inputPath){
    CharacterFromFileReader reader = new CharacterFromFileReader(inputPath);

    int state = 0;

    while(reader.hasNext()){
        char c = reader.next();

        switch(state){
            case 0:
                _toReturn = "";

                if(c=='<'){
                    state = 1;
                }

            case 1:
                if(c=='A'){
                    state = 2;
                }

            case 2:
                if(c=='U'){
                    state = 3;
                }
            case 3:
                if(c=='>'){
                    state = 4;
                }
            case 4:
                if(c=='<'){
                    state = 5;
                }
                if(c != '<'){
                    _toReturn = _toReturn + c;
                    state = 4;
                }
            case 5:
                if(c=='/'){
                    state = 6;
                }
            case 6:
                if(c=='A'){
                    state = 7;
                }
            case 7:
                if(c=='U'){
                    state = 8;
                }
            case 8:
                if(c=='>'){
                    System.out.println(_toReturn);
                    state = 0;
                }
                else{
                    state = 0;
                }
        }   

    }
}
```

}

However, when I run authorScanner(test.xml);, I get the following output:

```
>
>
```

Here is the contents of test.xml:

```
<AU>AUTHOR</AU>
```

What am I doing wrong? I believe I have the switch statement setup to search for `<AU>`, then having it append the following characters to a String called _toReturn. As it's appending the characters to the string, it should be checking for the character '<', and if it is present keep checking for the end tag `</AU>`. If the end tag is present, print out _toReturn.

Any tips/advice on how to write up a proper solution?

Comment: When you say that you "have to do this with a switch statement", is that actually a stated part of a school assignment?  I ask, because a switch statement is a terrible way to do this.

Comment: Yes, it is part of the assignment unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing `break;` statements after each case in your switch. If you add those, it looks like it might do what you intend.